# Load images from Local gallery In an Instant Like the Facebook App and Instagram App does

Tags: android, image, loading

I tried to load images from local gallery in an instant like the Facebook app and Instagram does with a cursor loader alongSide AsyncTaskLoader .

It takes about 20 seconds to load all the images. How to do it in an Instant?

Comment: Please show us your code, since as it stands, your question is too broad. There could be plenty of reasons why your image loading is slow, and we can only guess without the relevant code. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried anything on your own yet?